# How to export maps as a png from python lets-plot

Tags: lets-plot

I'm trying to create maps using python lets-plot and save them to file - note that I am running this on Databricks and not sure if that is relevant to this issue.

When I run the code below:

```
    !pip install lets-plot
    from lets_plot import * 
    LetsPlot.setup_html(offline=True)
    p = ggplot() + ggsize(700, 400)
    p = p + geom_livemap()
    ggsave(p, f"livemap.png")
```

I get the error 'The SVG size is undefined'

With the error raised in the code block below:

> lib/python3.10/site-packages/cairosvg/surface.py:209, in Surface.**init**(self, tree, output, dpi, parent_surface, parent_width, parent_height, scale, output_width, output_height, background_color, map_rgba, map_image)
> 204 self.cairo, self.width, self.height = self._create_surface(
> 205     width * self.device_units_per_user_units,
> 206     height * self.device_units_per_user_units)
> 208 if 0 in (self.width, self.height):
> --> 209     raise ValueError('The SVG size is undefined')
> 211 self.context = cairo.Context(self.cairo)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, exporting interactive map tiles to any but html format is not currently supported.

Comment: Is it possible to create and export a non-interactive map using lets-plot?

Comment: Yes, lets-plot support geopandas.GeoDataFrame in all relevant geometry layers (via either `data` or `map` parameters). Use `geom_imshow()` to add a background image. You could sometimes also find [geocoding](https://lets-plot.org/pages/geocoding.html) handy.